# Finding object through list of objects by finding a specific value

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, data-structures

I have list of dynamic objects. Dynamic because the numeric identity of the objects under data are always changing/increasing. I already have a variable that is defined as the amount of objects under data. The variable is as follows

```
var numOfFruits = Object.keys(Fruits.data).length
```

Then to go through each object under data I run this loop

```
for(numOfFruits in Fruits.data) { 
    var objectsUnderData = Fruits.data[numOfFruits];
}
```

I am wanting to be able to request the numeric identity of an object containing a certain value such as "Banana", "Apple", or "Grape". So I want to be able to use a pre-defined variable like `var name = "Apple"` and get the identity of the object it's in.

```
{
  "type": "fruits",
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "key": "Banana",
      "name": "Banana",
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "key": "Orange",
      "name": "Orange",
    },
    "3": {
      "id": 3,
      "key": "Grape",
      "name": "Grape",
    },
    "4": {
      "id": 4,
      "key": "Apple",
      "name": "Apple",
    }
 }
```

`}`

My Question: How do I use a specific value (name: "Apple", name: "Banana", etc...) to find the identity of the object it is under.

Comment: where is your specific problem statement and question? Take a  few minutes to read through [ask]

Comment: @charlietfl , I'm sorry about that, got a bit carried away. Did this clear it up? I tried to explain what I'm wanting to do to my best ability. I apologize if its unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See function `fruitFinder` below:

```js
function fruitFinder (Fruits, name) {
  for (fruit in Fruits.data) {
    if (Fruits.data[fruit].name == name) {
      return Fruits.data[fruit].id;
    }
  }
}

var Fruits = {
  "type": "fruits",
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "key": "Banana",
      "name": "Banana",
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "key": "Orange",
      "name": "Orange",
    },
    "3": {
      "id": 3,
      "key": "Grape",
      "name": "Grape",
    },
    "4": {
      "id": 4,
      "key": "Apple",
      "name": "Apple",
    }
  }
};

var name = "Apple";

console.log(fruitFinder(Fruits, name));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works very well! You are a life saver.